# Error:The element type "configuration" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</configuration>". in android studio gradle build

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using android studio as my android development. I installed android studio - 0.8.2, gradle - 1.12 to my Mac mini. When I try to open a gradle project or when I create new android project from android studio, always give the above error. Please help me to fix this.

Thanks ...

- I tried with gradle 2.0 & 2.1 (issue is happening).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue on this. Issue is partially installation on .gradle directory. So I delete the current .gradle directory and rebuild the project with new gradle installation.